# HTML why in IE 8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, hyperlink

Why in IE 8 (i cannot upgrade because on Windows XP it goes only up to v8) this works:

```
<body>
   <a href="page.html">
      <img src="myimage.jpg" />
   </a>
</body>
```

and this does not:

```
<body>
   <a href="page.html">
      <input type="button" name="mybutton" value="Go to page" />
   </a>
</body>
```

i just needed button looking link it works in every other browser and validates fine here http://validator.w3.org

Comment: You're missing a core component of this question. Why **what** in IE8. The only hint is in a `hyperlink` tag of yours. So I take it the link does not function and does not direct you to `page.html`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question and yes you can not upgrade past 8 if you have xp.

Comment: try wrapping your input button in a <form>...perhaps ie8 requires that?

Comment: Have you tried various <doctypes?

Comment: No i did not try doctypes because i dont want to/ dont want to  change what i have on rest of pages because of one page. 

P.S. Quesstion is why nothing happens when i click on the link.

Comment: @Petja: You should include the problem (nothing happens when clicking on the link) in the question.

Comment: @Petja: Maybe you can provide a link to the page? At what exactly do you try to click? In your code example the `a` element has only the `input` as content, so that is what should fire, I'd guess.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a link to look like a button, you style the link to look like a button:

```html
<a href="page.html" class="btn">Go to Page</a>
```

```css
.btn {
    color: #000;
    padding: 1px 6px;
    background: #EEE;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    font: 13px Helvetica, Arial, FreeSans, Verdana, Tahoma;
}

.btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: lightblue;
    border-color: #7EB4EA;
}
```

Which, when placed side-by-side with a similarly-styled button looks like this:

[image]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/g6faB/

Comment: Still dont feel like real button i am interested in having it look exactly the same. And i dont want to do any extra coding i'd rather change approach. I just trying to confirm if this is bug of IE 8?

Comment: @PetjaZaichikov You're doing it the **wrong** way. If you want a link to look like a button, you don't jam a `button` down inside it - you use CSS; that's what it's there for. Buttons are often *interactive*, and it is explicitly *illegal* to place interactive content within the `a` element.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an onClick event.

```
<input type="button" value="Google" onClick="javascript:location.href = 'http://google.com';" />
```

A button should be used to initiate an action via the server, such as a form submission.

A hyperlink should be used to navigate to another page or a client-side action (eg Javascript).

Comment: What if javascript disabled?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="page.html">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to page" />
</form>
```

Comment: Doesn't address the "why" aspect of the question.  Also performs a POST rather than a GET as written.

Comment: @EricJ. You're wrong: default value of `action` attribute of `form` element is `get`. Why something valid does not work in old IE? -- We all know the answer: it is a bug in IE8- that is fixed in IE9+.

Comment: @EricJ. There was a typo in my last [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594458/html-why-in-ie-8/14594720#comment20375113_14594720). Correct phrase is "default value of `method` attribute of `form` element is `get`".

Comment: you think i dont know how to make it work? i just need to know if that's IE8 bug or incorrect use W3 standard...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="image" src="myimage.jpg" alt="Submit" width="48" height="48">
```

As mentioned above, when you use input, dont forget to use it inside `<form>`.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5, the `input` element is not allowed as a child for the [`a` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element), because both are [interactive](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0) elements.

In HTML 4.01 it seems to be allowed (however, you'd need a block element around the `a` element, e.g. a `div`).

Comment: Does not work <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
 <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

 <div>
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
   <input type="button" value="Index.php" /> x
  </a>
 </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @Petja: Does the problem also occur with a HTML 4.01 doctype? (`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`) Not as a solution, just a test.